# trouble using Debug.MemoryInfo

Tags: android

I am trying to get memory usage values using this class, but all the class members are zero.  I am calling it like this:

```
android.os.Debug.MemoryInfo dbm = new android.os.Debug.MemoryInfo();
```

but them dbm.dalvikPss (and the other class members) are zero.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to call [Debug.getMemoryInfo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html#getMemoryInfo(android.os.Debug.MemoryInfo)) to populate it.

```
MemoryInfo dbm = new MemoryInfo();
Debug.getMemoryInfo(dbm);
```

Comment: bingo!  I thought that the constructor populated it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it based on the getProcessMemoryInfo(pids[])

```
    int myPid = android.os.Process.myPid();
    int[] pids = {myPid};
    Debug.MemoryInfo[] memoryInfoPids = am.getProcessMemoryInfo (pids );
```